# looking for an gentle introduction to gaussian processes (classification and regression)

Tags: references, gaussian-process

I am looking for a reasonably gentle introduction (with or without the maths) to Gaussian processes classification and regression. I am hoping to read a book that is not extremely intimidating and offers good intuition. I am have seen some lecture videos from Tubingen University, but I prefer to read the lecture slides myself instead of watching them.

I am reasonably good in maths and am familiar with probability, and basics of machine learning. Please suggest any available references.

Comment: "Gaussian process for Machine learning" book should work.http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/